# Correct way to include Navbar and Footer in every blade- Laravel 7?

Tags: laravel

I am trying to load Navbar and Footer views in every Laravel page, but not only the loading is slow, it also invalidates many CDNs and Plugins due to multiple inclusions of those files (like jQuery Validator Plugin). I am including a few codes to show my problems

I know I am not supposed to load every script (bootstrap and all) again and again in every view, but I am not sure what else to do

**Blade(any page)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

   <!-- Bootstrap CSS --!>
  //Bootstrap links here
   <!-- CSRF Token Meta Added -->
     <meta name="csrf-token" id="csrf-token" content="{{csrf_token()}}">

   <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
   <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  // Bootstrap javascipt etc. links here

   <!-- Sweet Alert -->
   //Sweet alert links

   <!-- jQuery validation plugin -->
//Validation plugin links

</head>
<body>
 @include('commonview.navbar')

//some view here


@include('commonview.footer')
```

**Navbar**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

   <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

   <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
   <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <!-- Data Table -->
   
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.22/r-2.2.6/sc-2.0.3/sb-1.0.0/sp-1.2.1/datatables.min.css"/>
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.22/r-2.2.6/sc-2.0.3/sb-1.0.0/sp-1.2.1/datatables.min.js"></script>


 <!-- Font awesome -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-vp86vTRFVJgpjF9jiIGPEEqYqlDwgyBgEF109VFjmqGmIY/Y4HV4d3Gp2irVfcrp" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>
<body>
 <header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark @if(auth()->check()) bg-dark @else bg-info @endif">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
       <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
           <li class="nav-item active">
               <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="contact">Contact Us</a>
           </li>
       </ul>

       <ul class="navbar-nav">
        @guest
           <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="login"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> Login</a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link"href="new_user"><i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i> Signup</a>
           </li>
           @endguest
           @auth
           <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fas fa-user"></i>
          {{Auth::user()->first_name}}
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{url('dashboard')}}"><i class="far fa-id-badge"></i></i> Profile</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{url('contactm')}}"><i class="fas fa-envelope-open-text"></i> Messages</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{url('logout')}}"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Logout</a>
        </div>
      </li>
           @endauth
       </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

**Footer**

```
Similar to Navbar with footer content (all scripts included here too)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this instead:

1. resources > views > layouts > app.blade.php

Basically saying that navigate to your **resources** folder, then the **views** folder and inside that create a folder called **layouts**. Within the created folder create a file named **app.blade.php**

2. Inside your **app.blade.php**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <!-- Stylesheet -->
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Data Table -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.22/r-2.2.6/sc-2.0.3/sb-1.0.0/sp-1.2.1/datatables.min.css" />

  <!-- Font awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-vp86vTRFVJgpjF9jiIGPEEqYqlDwgyBgEF109VFjmqGmIY/Y4HV4d3Gp2irVfcrp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!--add this to have this styles on all pages-->
  @yield('css')
  <!--for adding additional styles-->
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Navbar Area Start -->
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark @if(auth()->check()) bg-dark @else bg-info @endif">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
           <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
       </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="contact">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          @guest
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="login"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> Login</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="new_user"><i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i> Signup</a>
          </li>
          @endguest @auth
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fas fa-user"></i>
              {{Auth::user()->first_name}}
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{url('dashboard')}}"><i class="far fa-id-badge"></i></i> Profile</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{url('contactm')}}"><i class="fas fa-envelope-open-text"></i> Messages</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{url('logout')}}"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Logout</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          @endauth
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <!-- Navbar Area End -->


  @yield('content')
  <!--for adding your content-->

  <!-- Add Footer Area Start -->

  <!-- Add Footer Area End -->

  <!-- **** All JS Files here ***** -->
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.22/r-2.2.6/sc-2.0.3/sb-1.0.0/sp-1.2.1/datatables.min.js"></script>
  <!--add this to have this scripts on all pages-->
  @yield('scripts')
  <!--for adding additional scripts-->

</body>

</html>
```

3. On other pages you simply call

```html
@extends('layouts.app') //this loads the app.blade.php which has navbar & footer
@section('content') 
//content here 
@endsection 

// There's no need to have this if you're not adding additionall css styling for this page

@section('css') 
// additional css here
//I'm assumming that you don't want to add your datable css everywhere so add it here: the whole link tag
@endsection 

@section('scripts') 
// additional scripts
//I'm assumming that you don't want to add your datable js everywhere so add it here: the whole script tag
here @endsection
```

Comment: Please use my terminologies in your code. It is difficult for me to follow.

Comment: I updated the answer please have a look. if you face any problems let me know.

Comment: Seemed to work although I tried that in one page only. Thanks a lot for the solution

Comment: Nice. Now go build some awesome projects.

Answer (score 2):

You can structured your files like this.

1. You can create a seperate header file which includes your style sheet links. When you add them please consider the priority. Sometimes one stylesheet will overrides another one.
2. You can create seperate navbar file. which you have code for navbar. you can include header file into navbar file. then when we include navbar to somewhere header file will load automatically.
3. You can create a seperate footer file which includes your script links. When you add them please consider the priority.
4. you can include them to other files as you need.